# Convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ diverges whereas $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ converges.

Intuitively, I do not see the difference. If $n \to \infty$, the denominators in both fractions will be so big that the fraction approaches zero. So why doesn't both the series converge against zero?

I have read something about it, but I do not see the logic in it, and I guess it's quite obvious, so I hope someone can bring a good explanation.

Comment: Your intuition is misleading. You could just as well ask why both series do not **diverge to infinity**, since we are summing up an infinite amount of positive terms.

Comment: what does "converge against zero" mean? Does it mean converge to some quantity other than zero?

Comment: @Solitary: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=2\neq0$.

Comment: @barakmanos  So my guess is correct? Sorry I was actually asking English.

Comment: You don't want to start your sum with $n=0$.

Comment: @Solitary: I think that your guess is **not** correct. I tried to answer your question of "What does it mean to converge to some quantity other than zero".

Comment: I understood that concept of "converge to". Since the phrase "converge **against**" is rarely seen in the formal usage, I am asking OP if this phrase has some special meaning.

Comment: @Solitary In many languages you use a proposition whose literal meaning is closest to the English "against" when talking about convergence. (For example, German: "konvergenz *gegen*", Swedish: "konvergens *mot*"")

Comment: intuition is misleading.  If you want intuition, try to develop the idea that although both things tend to 0, some things tend to zero "faster" and other things tend to 0 "slower".  Consider a sequence where all the terms get small but the first two average 1/2, the next three terms average 1/3,  the next four terms average a fourth, and so on.  Thes goes to zero be way to slowly to do any good.  Adding "forever" just makes the thing get larger and larger and it'll blow up.  The first two terms add to one, the next three terms add to one, the next four terms add to one, etc.

Comment: I would think the phrase "converge against zero" means "converge to zero". The OP meant to say "converges to some constant" but logically mixed up it with "converge to zero".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is quite notorious specifically because it defies intuition. I agree with you, if we didn't know better, a "good" guess would be that they both converge.

One possible intuitive explanation for why the harmonic series diverges is this:

understand the relation between the harmonic series and the natural log. When we take the sum $1/1+1/2+1/3+\cdots$, we are finding a crude estimate for the integral of $1/x$ from $1$ to infinity. As you probably know, the integral of $1/x$ is the natural log, so we are really taking the limit of $\ln(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity.

Now it is somewhat easier to see why $\ln(x)$ keeps getting larger. The log of a very large number is asking "$e$ to what power gives this number?" Since we can keep finding larger numbers, there is no bound on $\ln(x)$.

Of course this is intended to be an intuitive connection. You can rigorously prove that the harmonic series diverges, while your other series converges.

Comment: Perhaps even more counter-intuitive is that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n\log n)^{-1}=\infty$ but $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n (\log n)^2)^{-1}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, you can group the terms,

$$\begin{alignat*}{2}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} &> \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} &= 1\\
\frac{1}{4} + \dots +\frac{1}{7} &> \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{4} &= 1\\
&\;\;\vdots&\vdots\;\;\;\,\\
\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1} &> \frac{1}{2^n}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^n} &= 1
\end{alignat*}$$

And $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges by comparison:

$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n^2} < \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n(n-1)} = \sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} = 1 -\frac{1}{N}\to 1 \quad(\text{telescoping}).
$$

These are the most intuitive explanations I've got.

Comment: The first proof uses the correct technique, but is implemented incorrectly. Note that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}.$ In the standard proof, the first two terms are grouped together, so that $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2},$ followed by the next $4, 8, \dots, 2^n$ terms, and these sums are equated with $\frac{1}{2}.$ The same conclusion can then be made.